# backbutton event (cordova) not affecting angularjs controller variables as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am getting unpredictable results from trying to integrate cordova.js into my angular controller.

```
    <div class="side-menu" ng-class="{'show_menu' : show_menu }" ng-swipe-left="show_menu = !show_menu"> // more stuff</div>
```

**INITAL CODE:**

```
   $scope.init =function() {

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", $scope.onDeviceReady, false);
    }

   $scope.onDeviceReady = function() {

       document.addEventListener("backbutton", $scope.onBackKeyDown, false);
    }
```

**WORKING:**

```
  $scope.onBackKeyDown = function($scope) {
        alert('backbutton pressed');
    }
```

**ALSO WORKING**

This calls a function (unlrelated to `show_menu` and succesfully changes the state of `show_menu`

```
$scope.onBackKeyDown = function() {
    $scope.filterby('dance');
    $scope.show_menu = !$scope.show_menu;
}
```

**NOT WORKING**

Quite simply nothing happens here

```
$scope.onBackKeyDown = function() {
    $scope.show_menu = !$scope.show_menu;
}
```

I have `$scope.show_menu` declared as false as soon the controller starts so I cant figure out why its relying on an unrelated function to be called before it starts to work.

EDIT:

I have discovered it is working but it waits until the following angularjs event. e.g. nothing happens with the menu, but then if I click trigger another event afterwards thats unrelated the menu, THEN the menu state changes.

Comment: May be i do not understand you question fully but did you try to pass the onBackKeyDown method into addEventListener(backbutton) again?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, but I edited the question just to be more clear. Basically I always used the top two functions , its variations of the third that seem to work or not work

Comment: You may want to use $apply() angular events and addEventListener are separate thats why sometimes you need to use "$apply()" because it updates the angular code. Alternately you may want to use a Factory or Service to keep track of the the variables that you are passing between events. One other options would be if you wanted to avoid using apply use the "controller as syntax" example ng-controller="AppCtrl as app" then attach your variables as app.show_menu  for example.

Comment: will comment here as well so @Adrian can see it: as an FYI - I've found that an empty `$timeout(function(){}, 0, true)` is safer than a `$apply()` the reason being that $timeout (with true) queues up a redraw immediately at the end of the last rewrite while `$apply()` can throw the `$digest already in progress` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use $apply() angular events and addEventListener are separate thats why sometimes you need to use "$apply()" because it updates the angular code. Alternately you may want to use a Factory or Service to keep track of the the variables that you are passing between events. One other options would be if you wanted to avoid using apply use the "controller as syntax" example ng-controller="AppCtrl as app" then attach your variables as app.show_menu for example.

Comment: as an FYI - I've found that an empty `$timeout(function(){}, 0, true)` is safer than a `$apply()` the reason being that $timeout (with true) queues up a redraw immediately at the end of the last rewrite while `$apply()` can throw the `$digest already in progress` error.